# Does StackExchange.Redis support client-side sharding?

Tags: stackexchange.redis

I'm shopping around for a nice c# Redis client.  StackExchange.Redis looks really nice, especially in regards to pipelining.  However, I can't find any mention of support for client-side sharding (which I need).  Am I missing something or is that not supported?

Comment: From what I have looked myself there isn't support, but there is support for redis cluster (server side cluster) or to use twemproxy

Comment: That's pretty much what I found as well. I was hoping I was missing something.  Frankly my interest in client-side sharding is for expediency.  I'll just have to take a little more time and use Twemproxy or something.